# Unable to build with electron-builder after migration from bower to yarn

Tags: npm, electron, bower, yarnpkg, electron-builder

I have an electron application using bower to resolve vendor deps and yarn for electron dependencies (node add-ons).

Because bower is deprecated I have migrated to yarn following this guide 
[how-to-migrate-away-from-bower](https://bower.io/blog/2017/how-to-migrate-away-from-bower/) 
that uses [bower-away](https://github.com/sheerun/bower-away)

App launch fine but when I tried to build with electron-builder I got a problem with node module resolution.

```
$node_modules/.bin/build 


• electron-builder version=20.8.1
• writing effective config file=dist/electron-builder-effective-config.yaml
Error: Unresolved node modules: angular, angular-animate, angular-aria, angular-messages, @bower_components/angular-translate, popper.js
at node_modules/electron-builder-lib/src/util/packageDependencies.ts:108:17
```

Comment: Seems that it's not downloading any package, could you please share your `package.json` and more information about your app tecnologies

Answer (score 0):

you should install of the package like this command
npm i angular --save

Answer (score 0):

Use this answer: https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/2529#issuecomment-465185995

```
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.0",
    "vue": "^2.6",
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "jquery": "1.9.1 - 3",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.7"
  }
}
```